# how to write and read from a single file in python

Tags: python, file

My project is to write and read different variables from a single txt file using python.

```
myFile = open("Mygame.txt","w")
skill = str(skill)
strength=str\n(strength)
myFile.write(skill)
myFile.write(strength)
myFile.close()
```

I've tried using \n but this doesn't seem to work with variables only print statements.

Comment: As it stands, I am confused on what you are asking.  Can you add some more details and/or code?

Comment: Use [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for variable read-write.

Comment: Could you share some of the code you have written to help us see where your problem might be?  What does the file you are reading look like?

Comment: What do you mean `\n` doesn't work with variables? Are you trying to read line by line? If so, use `readline`. You can find more information in the [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) about how to parse a file.

Comment: i need to write user1 strength,user1skill,user2strength and user2skill on diffrent lines in one text file then i have to read each pecfic line. Then make those numbers be the strength and skill variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
import shutil
with open('test') as old, open('newtest', 'w') as new:
    for line in old:
        if line.rsplit('|', 1)[-1].strip() == 'number3':
            new.write('this is replacement|number7\n')
        else:
            new.write(line)
shutil.move('newtest', 'test')
```

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with the question, does it?

Comment: i add a simple version of my write code to the post hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Put all stats or whatever you are saving in a list and try:

```
lines = [skill, strength]
myFile.writelines(lines).
```

**UPDATED**
This answer is based on the assumption of you want to use '\n' caracter for split the text in lines.

Comment: @spark It's called a list in python.